# Text rendering issue in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, rendering

Text in textbox and combobox do not render as they should be. Some letter desapears after the binding. The problem is partial : not every control in the view are affected.

The software is running on a hundred computer, but I got only one with the issue. They are all XP SP3.

It's do not look like a memory problem, because restarting the pc don't solve the problem.
As far as I know, other views are not affected.

Here is a screenshoot :

[image]

I'm out of ideas about this issue.

Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had this exact problem on an old MFC app, and it turned out to be the video driver. New driver = problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved any WPF XP display issues by updating (or in some cases backdating!) the video driver, or by [turning down the hardware acceleration](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/fixtheproblem/ht/hardwareacc.htm).